# Creating 2-way table, therein splitting of a single cell into many cells, comma separated delimiter,,,

Tags: python

How to create a groupby() for a 2-way table for multiple elements in a single cell? How do we split them using split(',')? Another question how do we invent the code????
Gopalakrishnan Kumar.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment, your question is not very clear. Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to formulate a good question. In this case, you definitely ought to provide a sample of your data, along with the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Just getting back to you, sorry Sir!!!

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer by using explode() code.